# Too much deletion: [deleted-accounts], [deleted-users], and [account-destruction]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, tag-synonyms, burninate-system

*This is going meta-meta, hold on tight..!*

There seems to be 3 tags that have to do with account/user-deletion:

[deleted-accounts](/questions/tagged/deleted-accounts) (221 questions as of writing):

> This tag is for questions about user accounts that have been deleted or the process of that deletion.

[deleted-users](/questions/tagged/deleted-users) (27 questions as of writing):

> This tags is for questions about deleted users.

and [account-destruction](/questions/tagged/account-destruction) (2 questions as of writing) without any excerpt/wiki.

I believe [deleted-accounts](/questions/tagged/deleted-accounts) and [deleted-users](/questions/tagged/deleted-users) means the same. If so, should either be burninated/synonymized? Otherwise, can someone explain the difference?

I'm not sure about the [account-destruction](/questions/tagged/account-destruction), but it seems it's focused more on spammer (or any abusive) account/user. Does this tag deserve to stand alone, or should it be burninated/synonymized too?

Comment: Agree we should change [tag:deleted-users] in existing questions to [tag:deleted-accounts]. As for [tag:account-destruction], I created that tag to make it clear I mean the process of destroying an account. It's about the process, not about the spammer so believe it better have a tag of its own.

Comment: Also on users tags https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306629/are-anonymous-visitors-not-anonymous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've [proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313166/162102) a synonym of deleted-users -> deleted-accounts.  Merger would be better, as explained there, but a synonym is a start.

[account-destruction](/questions/tagged/account-destruction) is different; destroying an account has specific consequences that do not apply to other deletions.  While both the action and the tag are rare, it's worth keeping the distinction, especially if we find the other questions about destruction that don't yet have this tag and add it.