# Are [anonymous-visitors] not [anonymous]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I once thought [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors) aren't always [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous), but that made no sense. So here comes the topic.

Tag wiki excerpts:

> [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous): for questions regarding anonymous users
>
> [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors): This tag is for questions about the anonymous users, i.e. users who haven't registered on the Stack Exchange site or browsing it anonymously (not logged in).

Usage: same

[anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors) has only 1/4 as much questions tagged as [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous), so it's better that the longer one is merged into the shorter one.

Comment: You might want to link to the [synonym page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/anonymous-visitors/synonyms), since somebody already proposed this synonym (but it still needs votes!)

Comment: I think the process of getting synonyms is flawed.

Comment: @Laurel My proposal is the reverse...

Comment: I would prefer [anonymous] to be a synonym of [anonymous-visitors] for the reasons I explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296815/349538).

Comment: @Ano You're right, it definitely is. Already to even *suggest* a synonym, you need to have a score of 5 in that tag which I think is completely unreasonable (see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203760/349538) which I totally agree with). And when someone actually managed to suggest a synonym (which is probably quite rare), it still has to be reviewed, but chances are that nobody will see the suggestion since there is no review queue for synonym suggestions.

Comment: @DonaldDuck And because of that crappy suggestion & reviewing mechanism, Meta is the correct place for a synonym for most people.