# Overlap? [deleted-accounts] vs. [deleted-users]

Tags: discussion, support, synonym-request, ambiguous-tags, clean-up

[deleted-accounts](/questions/tagged/deleted-accounts) 252 questions

> `Use it for questions about user accounts that have been deleted or the process of that deletion.`
>
> [deleted-accounts](/questions/tagged/deleted-accounts) is for questions about user accounts that have been deleted, or the process of that deletion.

[deleted-users](/questions/tagged/deleted-users) 29 questions

> `This tags is for questions about deleted users.`
>
> *[no wiki]*

Is there a functional difference between these two? It seems to me that the latter should be a synonym of the former.

(Granted, there's only 29 questions for the latter so these could be manually fixed, but I think it would be recreated.)

Comment: It seems [this issue has come up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296928/21960), but there was no definitive action taken.

Comment: It would be better to merge them than to edit 29 questions, but a merge requires a moderator (i.e. CM, here on main meta).

Comment: The synonym I proposed (see my answer) needs one more vote.

Comment: @ale the synonym exists now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently I have a high-enough score in the tag to propose a synonym, so I've done that.  If you have a score of at least 5 in the tag you can [vote on the suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/deleted-accounts/synonyms).

I think a merge would be better than a synonym -- when you type "deleted" and see the auto-completions, I think you'd recognize "account" even if you were thinking "user" -- but merges require somebody who's a moderator on Meta.SE to implement, while the community can create the synonym.  So let's at least do that much now.  (And it can always be merged later, when a passing CM decides it's a good idea and has time to do it.)

**Update:** the synonym has now been created.